# React Navigation Active Tab color cover SafeArea

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm working on an app using React Navigation Bottom Tabs and I want to highlight the active tab with a different color then when it's inactive. Currently, I have the correct highlight color, but that color is not filling up the safe area at the bottom of the phone:

[image: bottom tabs]

And here's a snippet of my code:

```
        <MainTabs.Navigator
            initialRouteName="HomeTab"
            screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
                headerShadowVisible: false,
                tabBarStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: theme.colors.primaryColor,
                },
                tabBarActiveBackgroundColor: theme.colors.secondaryColor,
                tabBarInactiveBackgroundColor: theme.colors.primaryColor,
                tabBarActiveTintColor: theme.colors.white,
                tabBarInactiveTintColor: theme.colors.white,
                tabBarLabelStyle: {
                    fontSize: 12,
                    alignSelf: "center",
                    textAlign: "center",
                    fontFamily: theme.font.familyBold,
                },
            })}
        >
```

Comment: You will need to disable the default Tab Navigator as React Navigation handles safe area in the default header and implement your own using https://reactnavigation.org/docs/handling-safe-area/#hiddencustom-header-or-tab-bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue, I found out how to fix it. Here's my code below:

```
        <MainTabs.Navigator
            initialRouteName="HomeTab"
            safeAreaInsets={{ bottom: 0 }}
            screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
                headerShadowVisible: false,
                tabBarIconStyle: {
                    marginTop: 5,
                },
                tabBarStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: theme.colors.primaryColor,
                    height: 85,
                },
                tabBarActiveBackgroundColor: theme.colors.secondaryColor,
                tabBarInactiveBackgroundColor: theme.colors.primaryColor,
                tabBarActiveTintColor: theme.colors.white,
                tabBarInactiveTintColor: theme.colors.white,
                tabBarLabelStyle: {
                    fontSize: 12,
                    alignSelf: "center",
                    textAlign: "center",
                    fontFamily: theme.font.familyBold,
                    marginBottom: insets.bottom,
                },
            })}
        >
```

Basically just added `safeAreaInsets` and then `marginBottom` in the tab bar label style. the `insets` variable comes from using `useSafeAreaInsets` from `react-native-safe-area-context`